# Formal notation for key value mapping with versioning and injective function for version

Tags: functions, notation

I would like to know what is a correct formal notation for representing a 
state where the state is defined by

$ K \to (V x N)$

where K is the key, V is the value and N is the infinite ordered set of version numbers.
An injective function f takes an element of N and returns the next version number.

Comment: Might be just me, but I'm not really familiar with what you mean by 'state', 'version number' and 'key'? What's the context?

Comment: like dictionary but with versioned values. f returns the next version number.
have it from here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arch-deep-dive.html#state

Comment: Looks like more of a question for stackoverflow.com.

Comment: why stackoverflow? I want a formal math notation for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For formal notation, I'd probably use exactly what the source page uses, just written with standard mathematical typography instead of ASCII: *A piece of state is modeled as an element of a mapping $K \to (V \times N)$.* (Then explain what $K$, $V$, and $N$ are.)

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: thank you, I think I will just use this